# R function with single argument to rename/combine variables with a similar stem

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments, parameter-passing

As an occasional R programmer I have a poor grasp of how to complete programming style tasks which when I want to use the equivalent of shell `$variables`, or SAS `&macroparameters`. (Which I am not sure exist in R?)

I am trying to write a function to create a new variable in a dataframe from existing variables with a common stem. For example, I want to create:

```
df1$stem_new<- df1$stem_old1 + df1$stem_old2
```

repeatedly, where the `stem` part of the variable name will change.

Naively I want a function `groupvars` like this:

```
groupvars <- function(stem){
df1$'stem'_new <- df1$'stem'_old1 + df1$'stem'_old2
}
```

but I'm unsure how to best achieve this in R. Any help or pointers towards useful functions would be appreciated. I've tried messing around with `paste0()` and `names()` but no luck so far.

Ben

Comment: Use df1[[paste0(stem,'_new')]] and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small example:

```
# example of original data
df = data.frame(stem_old1 = 1:3,
                stem_old2 = 11:13,
                z = 1:3)

df

#   stem_old1 stem_old2 z
# 1         1        11 1
# 2         2        12 2
# 3         3        13 3

# function (input dataframe and the column name pattern)
# 1. get the columns that match the pattern, calculate the row sums and save them as column v in your dataset
# 2. update column name from v to your pattern plus "_new"
# 3. return updated dataframe
f = function(d, x) {
  d$v = rowSums(d[,grepl(x, names(d))])
  names(d)[names(d) == "v"] = paste0(x,"_new")
  d }

# apply function
f(df, "stem")

#   stem_old1 stem_old2 z stem_new
# 1         1        11 1       12
# 2         2        12 2       14
# 3         3        13 3       16
```

*Note* that the function initially stores the calculated sums in a (new) column named `v`. So, if your original dataset already has a column named `v` there will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Antonios, really appreciate that